# not able to install wtp components in ADT

Tags: java, eclipse, adt, eclipse-wtp

I am getting crazy with that ptoblem. I have installed the ADT Eclipse version and implement besides the Android application the server side logic.
I need to test it with my local tomcat. For that I want to add a new server project.
Unfortunality the most of the WTP Plugins are not part of that ADT version.
If I try to install the new wtp software via Help->Install new Software...
I get this message:

```
    Your original request has been modified.
"Eclipse XML Editors and Tools" is already present because other installed software      
requires it.  It will be added to the installed software list.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 3.3.2.v201112072049-    
7F7AFO7C25ToiIbpoiuW12GT78Mciy6W7iwuxaco (org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group   
3.3.2.v201112072049-7F7AFO7C25ToiIbpoiuW12GT78Mciy6W7iwuxaco)
Missing requirement: Structured Source JSP Model 1.2.402.v201112071853   
(org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core 1.2.402.v201112071853) requires 'package 
javax.servlet.jsp.tagext [2.0.0,2.2.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Java Web Development Core 3.3.2.v201112072049-  
7Q7DGLAFE9LeAHGQwz0Yz0Nmuitz01z01sRxi387 (org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature.feature.group   
3.3.2.v201112072049-7Q7DGLAFE9LeAHGQwz0Yz0Nmuitz01z01sRxi387)
To: org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core [1.2.402.v201112071853]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 3.3.2.v201112072049-  
7F7AFO7C25ToiIbpoiuW12GT78Mciy6W7iwuxaco (org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group  
3.3.2.v201112072049-7F7AFO7C25ToiIbpoiuW12GT78Mciy6W7iwuxaco)
To: org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature.feature.group [3.3.2.v201112072049-
7Q7DGLAFE9LeAHGQwz0Yz0Nmuitz01z01sRxi387]
```

I run ADT in admin mode without succed.
Does anybody knows a solution for that?

Thx in advance
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These messages:

```
Software being installed: ...
```

Make me think that one of the previous plug-in installations broke your Eclipse configuration (there were some plug-ins that were installed but not completely or not configured properly). Based on the logs, I'd do this:

1. Uninstall the plug-ins that are *"being installed"* (ain't sure if it can be done easily, I see segments in the log that say you're on the 3.3.2 platform build, in which I can't remember if this feature was available).
2. Stop Eclipse
3. Delete the `workspace/.metadata/logs` file
4. Start Eclipse
5. Check in the logs if you have no erroneous plug-in configuration
6. Try reinstalling the WTP plug-ins

Hopefully that will solve your issues.

Comment: wired problem. After I have deinstalled the xml plugin, the installation works...

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the plugins conflict each other out :-) But glad you solved the problem.